# javascript polygon intersection

Tags: javascript, polygon, intersection

I have used the code in the following :
http://www.amphibian.com/blogstuff/collision.html. in the html test file I have changed the the first triangle to

```
triangle1.addPoint({"x":-20, "y":-20});
triangle1.addPoint({"x":-20, "y":20});
triangle1.addPoint({"x":20, "y":20});
triangle1.addPoint({"x":20, "y":10});
triangle1.addPoint({"x":10, "y":10});
triangle1.addPoint({"x":10, "y":-20});
```

now when I move the other triangle with inside this shape before crossing it gives me wrongly intersection. Any idea where could be the problem?

Comment: I dont understand your question and problem

Comment: how does a triangle have 6 points? how do you have negative values for coordinates?

Comment: Shouldn't the last three triangles be triangle2, not triangle1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All right, I set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/9FAGJ/) for anyone else wanting to play with this. Here are the results:

[image: Demonstration of the problematic intersection]

The script makes use of the Separating Axis Theorem or (as Wikipedia calls it) [Hyperplane separation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem), as explained in the source of `polygon.js`:

```
/*
 *  To detect intersection with another Polygon object, this
 *  function uses the Separating Axis Theorem. It returns false
 *  if there is no intersection, or an object if there is. The object
 *  contains 2 fields, overlap and axis. Moving the polygon by overlap
 *  on axis will get the polygons out of intersection.
 */
Polygon.prototype.intersectsWith = function(other) {
```

**This theorem only applies to convex polygons.** Your shape is not convex as it has a "dent" in it. That's why the script incorrectly reports that the shapes are intersecting. If you need to make it work with concave shapes, you'll have to make it first split the concave shape up in separate convex parts and then apply the theorem to all individual parts. Obviously, this makes the script more complex as you need to iterate over the cross product of the concave parts of two shapes.

Comment: Many thanks. I Think I 'll go with o(N2) algorithm as my polygons are not very big and not many of them. Just was curios why this doesn't work. Many thanks for information.

Comment: Any thoughts hove to move the colliding shape/s?

Comment: @yckart There was a slight misconfiguration in the fiddle, the JavaScript code was wrapped in a MooTools onLoad handler and thus the events weren't properly bound. It should work now, try again.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Yeah, that was clear. However, what I meaned is something like this: http://html5quintus.com/quintus/examples/touch/

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Here's what I've done so far: http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/D9Pzb/2/

Comment: @MattiasBuelens polygon.js no longer there

Comment: @setec [Found it again!](https://gist.github.com/cwleonard/e124d63238bda7a3cbfa) Fiddle updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my not too complicated implementation of finding the intersection polygon of two polygons.

It works for convex and concave polygons, but not for complex (self-intersecting) polygons. 
Algorithm is fairly similar to the one presented in [Margalit & Knott](http://gvu.gatech.edu/people/official/jarek/graphics/papers/04PolygonBooleansMargalit.pdf).

Its complexity is about 4*n1*n2, where n1 and n2 are numbers of vertices in polygons whose intersection is being calculated.

It is a single standalone .js file. A 'Polygon' is regarded any javascript array of 2D Points. A 'Point' is any javascript object with x and y numeric properties.

Implementing the Union functionality on top of existing one should not be a problem and I will do it probably soon.

[Intersection of 2D polygons](http://freshplayer.blogspot.com/2014/04/intersection-of-two-2d-polygons-in.html)

Comment: Link is broken. Please include the code in the comment itself.

Comment: links are not working.