# Randomly Generate HTML Canva Objects

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am creating a pattern in a HTML canvas for a challenge.

How would I randomly generate shapes like the ones coded below to form a pattern similar to the picture. I created one version by generating the code with drawscript in Illustrator but it is far from ideal, how could I do the same with a loop?

[image]

Thanks

```
//triangles
ctx.fillStyle="rgb(75,128,166)";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(824,92);
ctx.lineTo(796,140);
ctx.lineTo(767,92);
ctx.lineTo(824,92);
ctx.fill();

//circles
ctx.fillStyle="rgba(35,121,67,0.8)";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(869,263);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(869,253,861,244,850,244);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(839,244,831,253,831,263);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(831,274,839,283,850,283);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(861,283,869,274,869,263);
ctx.fill();
```

Comment: see procedural noise and procedural randomness

Comment: for example procedural randoness can be this: trhrow a coin, if the coin is `head` paint this area and the next, else move two steps `north` and one step `east`, and so on on the new point untill ending criteria are reached

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_generation, https://procbuildthesis.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/controlling-randomness/

Comment: Visually, it looks like the circles are not really random--lots of rows and columns of circles. Do you want more randomness, or is this organization what you're looking for?

Comment: I've made some progress toward an answer but I don't have time to work out some of the geometry, perhaps this can help someone else: http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/2j2xqre0/

Answer (score 4):

You can make a square grid that is skewed over for the triangles, then have a random insert as well as a random diagonal divide of that rectangle so it appears as a triangle.

For the circles we can use a pseudo-hexagonal system which means the circles will be placed in hexagonal positions just compensating for being a circle and not an actual hexagon.

[image: snap]

## The Triangles

- First define a plain grid but one that overlaps the drawing area (which is one approach, a alternative approach is to wrap the coordinates but this require tracking the transform, so brute-force in this example)
- Transform with skew so that the vertical alignment will turn diagonal
- Define coverage, fill cells which in turn define if split, if upper part etc.

How to cover with random cells can be done in several ways, below is just one approach. Other can be using a fixed grid system and iterate over it using a step based on coverage (require tracking remainder for accuracy). A third to fill up coverage of cells, then random sort the array to shuffle the cells around.

## The Circles

Also here a grid will be used, but since we're gonna pack the vertical space to approximate a hexagonal grid, we need to compensate for it. The layout will be done with these factors:

- vertical distance = diameter x sqrt(3) x 0.5 **<sup>1)</sup>**
- horizontal distance = radius (offset toggled every 2. row)

(**<sup>1)</sup>** thanks to @Jason and his answer for reminding me of this!)

To compensate for the vertical "packed" circles, as they won't fill out the bottom, we use inverse of sqrt(3) * 0.5 (`1 / (sqrt(3) * 0.5)`).

## Final Result

Combining both of these into a single canvas will result in this:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    w = canvas.width,
    h = canvas.height,
    cellsY = 14,                     // cells Y for triangles
    cellsX = cellsY * 2,             // cells X times two to overlap skew
    cw = w / cellsX * 2,             // cell width and height         
    ch = h / cellsY,
    toggle, cx = 0, cy,              // for circles
    cells = 25,                      // cells for cirles + comp. (see below)
    deltaY = 0.8660254037844386,     // = sqrt(3) * 0.5
    deltaYI = 1 / deltaY,            // inverse deltaY
    grid = new Uint8Array((cells * cells * deltaYI)|0), // circles "booleans"
    i;

// Calc and Render Triangles ---

// main transform: skew
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0.51, 1, -cellsX * cw * 0.5, 0);
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(90, 146, 176)";

// fill random cells based on likely cover:
var cover = 0.67,                    // how much of total area to cover
    biasDiv = 0.6,                   // bias for splitting cell
    biasUpper = 0.5,                 // bias for which part to draw
    count = cellsX * cellsY * cover, // coverage
    tris = [],
    x, y, d, u, overlap;             // generate cells

for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  overlap = true;
  while (overlap) { // if we have overlapping cells
    x = (Math.random() * cellsX) | 0;
    y = (Math.random() * cellsY) | 0;
    overlap = hasCell(x, y);
    if (!overlap) {
      d = Math.random() < biasDiv;   // divide cell?
      u = Math.random() < biasUpper; // if divided, use upper part?
      tris.push({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        divide: d,
        upper: u
      })
    }
  }
}

function hasCell(x, y) {
  for (var i = 0, c; c = tris[i++];) {
    if (c.x === x && c.y === y) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

// render
for (i = 0; i < tris.length; i++) renderTri(tris[i]);
ctx.fill();  // fill all sub-paths

function renderTri(t) {
  var x = t.x * cw,                  // convert to abs. position
    y = t.y * ch;
  if (t.divide) {                    // create triangle
    ctx.moveTo(x + cw, y);           // define common diagonal
    ctx.lineTo(x, y + ch);
    t.upper ? ctx.lineTo(x, y) : ctx.lineTo(x + cw, y + ch);
  }
  else {
    ctx.rect(x, y, cw, ch);          // fill complete cell
  }
}

// Calc and Render Circles ---

cover = 0.5,                         // how much of total area to cover
count = Math.ceil(grid.length * cover); // coverage
cw = ch = w / cells;

ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);       // reset transforms
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(32, 141, 83)";
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";  // blend mode instead of alpha

if (ctx.globalCompositeOperation !== "multiply") ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5; // for IE

for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  overlap = true;
  while (overlap) {                  // if we have overlapping cells
    x = (Math.random() * cells) | 0;           // x index
    y = (Math.random() * cells * deltaYI) | 0; // calc y index + comp
    overlap = hasCircle(x, y);                 // already has circle?
    if (!overlap) {
      grid[y * cells + x] = 1;                 // set "true"
    }
  }
}

function hasCircle(x, y) {
  return grid[y * cells + x] === 1;
}

// render
ctx.beginPath();
cy = ch * 0.5;                               // start on Y axis
for (y = 0; y < (cells * deltaYI)|0; y++) {  // iterate rows + comp.
  toggle = !(y % 2);                         // toggle x offset
  for (x = 0; x < cells; x++) {              // columns
    if (grid[y * cells + x]) {               // has circle?
      cx = x * cw + (toggle ? cw * 0.5 : 0); // calc x
      ctx.moveTo(cx + cw * 0.5, cy);         // creat sub-path
      ctx.arc(cx, cy, cw * 0.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI); // add arc
      ctx.closePath();                       // close sub-path
    }
  }
  cy += ch * deltaY;                         // add deltaY
}
ctx.fill();                                  // fill all at once
```

```css
body {background:#777}
canvas {padding:50px;background: rgb(226, 226, 226)}
```

```html
<canvas width=600 height=600></canvas>
```

There is room for a refactoring here and the randomizing functions are not the best performance wise, but it should be enough to get you going. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Creating circles is done more easily with `context.arc` rather than stringing together 4 Bezier curves (and the 4 Bezier curves don't produce a perfect circle like `arc` does).

**Adding random Circles**

If you want a more randomized coverage of circles, you must try adding one circle at a time and make sure that every new try doesn't overlap any existing circles.

[image]

Here's example code and a Demo that adds as many random circles as necessary to cover 40% of the canvas area:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var PI2=Math.PI*2;
var radius=10;
var radiusTest=(2*radius)*(2*radius);
var circleCoverageDesired=.40;
var circleCount=parseInt((cw*ch*circleCoverageDesired)/(Math.PI*radius*radius))+1;
var circles=[];

ctx.fillStyle='green';
ctx.globalAlpha=0.25;

addRandomCircles();

function addRandomCircles(){
  // give up after "tries" to avoid unsolvable patterns
  var tries=circleCount*200;
  while(tries>0 && circles.length<circleCount){
    var x=Math.random()*(cw-radius*2)+radius/2;
    var y=Math.random()*(ch-radius*2)+radius/2;
    testRandomCircle(x,y);
    tries--;
  }
}


function testRandomCircle(x,y){
  for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
    var c=circles[i];
    var dx=x-c.x;
    var dy=y-c.y;
    if(dx*dx+dy*dy<=radiusTest){
      return(false);
    }
  }
  var circle={x:x,y:y};
  circles.push(circle);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,PI2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  var pct=parseInt((Math.PI*radius*radius*circles.length)/(cw*ch)*100);
  $('#count').text('Added: '+circles.length+' of '+circleCount+' needed circles for '+pct+'% coverage.');
  return(true);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 id=count>Count</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

**Adding random Triangles**

Adding random triangles requires the same restriction as adding random circles. You must add one new triangle at a time and make sure that every new triangle doesn't overlap any existing triangles.

Testing if any 2 polygons (eg triangles) overlap can be done using the *Separating Axis Theorem*,

This previous Stackoverflow answer by Mattias Buelens illustrates how the Separating Axis Theorem can be implemented: [javascript polygon intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838389/javascript-polygon-intersection/10838831#10838831)

Answer (score 1):

OK Here is a function that will render this art style on any canvas on a page (with options for sizes and shape frequency, and taking the canvas size into account):

```js
function art(options, canvas) {
    var surface = document.getElementById(canvas),
        context = surface.getContext("2d"),
        row,
        col,
        triangleDirection = 1,
        triangleSize = options.triangle.size,
        circleSize = options.circle.size,
        circleStep = Math.sqrt(3) * circleSize * 2,
        circleOffset = 0;

    function shouldDraw(chances) {
        return Math.random() < chances;
    }

    function drawTriangle(x, y, direction, size, ctx) {
        ctx.fillStyle = options.triangle.color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, y - (direction * size));
        ctx.lineTo(x - (direction * size), y + (direction * size));
        ctx.lineTo(x + (direction * size), y + (direction * size));
        ctx.lineTo(x, y - (direction * size));
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.strokeStyle = options.triangle.color;
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function drawCircle(x, y, size, ctx) {
        //circles
        ctx.fillStyle = options.circle.color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, size, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fill();
    }

    //Draw Tiangles
    for (col = 1; col < (surface.width / triangleSize); col++) {
        for (row = 1; row < (surface.height / triangleSize); row++) {
            if (shouldDraw(options.triangle.density)) {
                drawTriangle(row * triangleSize, col * triangleSize * 2, triangleDirection, triangleSize, context);
            }
            //Swap direction
            triangleDirection = -1 * triangleDirection;
        }
    }
    //Draw Circles
    for (row = 1; row < (surface.height / circleSize) - 1; row++) {
        for (col = 1; col < (surface.width / circleStep) - 1; col++) {
            if (shouldDraw(options.circle.density)) {
                drawCircle((row * circleSize), (col * circleStep) + circleOffset, circleSize, context);
            }
        }
        //swap offset by row
        if (row % 2 === 0) {
            circleOffset = circleStep / 2;
        } else {
            circleOffset = 0;
        }
    }
}

art({triangle: {size:24, density: 0.7, color: 'rgb(75,128,166)'}, circle: {size: 14, density: 0.2, color: 'rgba(35,121,67,0.8)'}}, 'surface')
```

```css
#surface {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='surface' height='600' width='600' />
```

Here are some highlights to consider:

The triangle pattern is a oscillating pattern of up and down triangles, so generalizing your triangle code into a function that can draw this based on arguments will make your code easier to follow.

The circle pattern oscillates, but this time its row by row and shifted left and right.  To figure this out I needed to dust off some basic geometry.  Looking at three circles on top of each other:

[image]

you can see that their height moves in steps equal to the radius (`circleSize` in the code).  However the distance they are spaced side to side it trickier, however when you see this as an equilateral triangle you can calculate this as the height of that triangle or:

[image]

, then you can see that the variables are meant to be spaced twice that distance, which after you reduce the fractions turns into: `Math.sqrt(3) * circleSize * 2`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You mean divided, `Math.sqrt(3) * circleSize / 2` ? Nice approach btw. (upvote)

Comment: I just dumped my progress thus far because I couldn't let go of this question, I think there are some row/col transposition errors as well.  I think you nailed the answer in your final solution.