# Check if polygon is in viewport

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have 250 polygons each with 100-300 points. **How to check which polygons are in viewport?**

Logical thing to do would be to check for each point for each polygon if they are in viewport but this seems extremely expensive and stupid. **Do I have any other options and if yes, what options?**

**My other thoughts:**

- Use bounding box - drawback is that it has only 4 points and it might give false negatives
- Make invisible simplifiled polygons with less points - too much extra work, data, resource usage

---

Following code iterates through all 250 polygons and each polygon's 100-300 points and checks in it's in viewport. I think of myself as a beginner in programming but this really don't seem like a good idea, especially if I need it to happen each time bounds has been changed / map has been dragged.

```
google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'bounds_changed', function( ) {

    var viewport = map.getBounds();

    var polygons = [array of polygons];
    var polygonsCount = polygons.length;

    // Polygons
    for(a = 0; a < polygonsCount; a++) {

        var polygonPoints = polygons[a].getPath(); // Array of points
        var inBounds = false;

        var pointsCount = polygonPoints.length;

        // Points
        for(b = 0; b < pointsCount; b++) {

            if(viewport.contains(polygonPoints[b])) { 

                inBounds = true; 
                return false;  // No need to continue loop if we found one 
            } 
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: You could keep track of the polygon points closest to the edge of the bounds but NOT inside the bounds for each side of the map, then when bounds change you only need to update which polygons are inside the map IFF any of the 4 points you were keeping track of are now inside, as opposed to checking all 250*n points everytime bounds update. Do the same with the nearest points on the inside incase they shrink the bounds.

Comment: You could also only check 1 point on each polygon and see if it's within "n" of the edge of the bounds, where n is the diameter of the circle that would circumscribe the polygon, IFF thats true then iterate all points, else move on to next polygon

Comment: These two tactics should drastically decrease your computation time, like 1% of what it was. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry I don't know javascript or google maps API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could utilize the following function to determine whether the polygon is located inside a map viewport or not:

```
function containsPolygon(map,polygon) {
    return polygon.getPaths().getArray().every(function (path) {
        return path.getArray().every(function(coord) {
            return map.getBounds().contains(coord);
        });
    });
}
```

**Example**

```js
var g_polygongs = [];
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 3,
        center: { lat: 24.886, lng: -70.268 },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });

    //generate polygons
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var startLng = getRandomArbitrary(-90.0, 0.0);
        var startLat = getRandomArbitrary(0.0, 60.0);
        var coords = [
            { lat: startLat, lng: startLng },
            { lat: startLat - 6.0, lng: startLng + 4.0 },
            { lat: startLat + 6.0, lng: startLng + 8.0 },
            { lat: startLat, lng: startLng }
        ];
        g_polygongs.push(createPolygon(map,coords));
    }


    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {

      g_polygongs.forEach(function(p) {
          if (containsPolygon(map, p)) {
              p.setOptions({ strokeWeight: 2.0, fillColor: 'green' });
          } else {
              p.setOptions({ fillColor: 'orange' });
          }

      });
    });

}


function containsPolygon(map,polygon) {
    return polygon.getPaths().getArray().every(function (path) {
        return path.getArray().every(function(coord) {
            return map.getBounds().contains(coord);
        });
    });
}





function createPolygon(map,coords) {
    // Construct the polygon.
    var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: coords,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    poly.setMap(map);
    return poly;
}


function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#map {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/p7nmwbwf/)

Comment: This seems to check every point and might result some performance issues when my polygons contains hundreds of points or do I misunderstand your code? Also, is there a way to add _padding_ so that even polygons near the borders and a little bit outside the borders gets counted as _visible_?

Comment: that's right, it could affect the performance since in `map.getBounds().contains` function  we verify whether map contains coordinate of every vertices of polygon

Answer (score 0):

Using the bounding boxes should be a straight forward process, and provide a good reduction in comparisons. If that passes then you could still check each point for a definite result.

The [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#LatLngBounds) has an intersects function you could use.

You would want to precalculate the bounds of each polygon, but this only needs to happen once or when they update. Google maps doesn't offer a bounds function but you can create it.

**GetBounds For Polygon**

```
if (!google.maps.Polygon.prototype.getBounds) {

    google.maps.Polygon.prototype.getBounds=function(){
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds()
        this.getPath().forEach(function(element,index)  {bounds.extend(element)})
        return bounds
    }
}
```

**Precalc bounds for each;**

```
function calcBounds(){
    for(a = 0; a < polygonsCount; a++) {
            polygons[a].bounds = polygons[a].getBounds(); //precalculated
    }
}
```

**Add the extra test in your event handler.**

```
google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'bounds_changed', function( ) {

    var viewport = map.getBounds();

    var polygons = [array of polygons];
    var polygonsCount = polygons.length;

    // Polygons
    for(a = 0; a < polygonsCount; a++) {
        var bounds = polygons[a].bounds; //precalculated
        if(viewport.intersects(bounds)){ //only continue if basic test passes
            var polygonPoints = polygons[a].getPath(); // Array of points
            var inBounds = false;

            var pointsCount = polygonPoints.length;

            // Points
            for(b = 0; b < pointsCount; b++) {

                if(viewport.contains(polygonPoints[b])) { 

                    inBounds = true; 
                    return false;  // No need to continue loop if we     found one 
                } 
            }
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay.. But how to solve the problem where map is zoomed in and we are _in the middle of the polygon_ or _in the middle or bounding box border_? None of the points are shown, how to still know if _this_ polygon is shown?

Comment: Well the initial bounding box intersects test should work for that. You just need to refine your polygon intersects function to something more advanced than simply point comparison. Should be resources around for that. Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10838831/1522857