# Polygon physics in 2d platformer (Pure JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am making a platformer game and I have a system where level creators are able to make any block by specifying the vertices. The problem with this is the physics, I have the vertices of the shape but have no idea how to detect and resolve the collision between the (square) player and the polygon blocks. Here is a screenshot of the game: [image]

If anyone could point me in the right direction that'd be great. Thank you in advance : )

Comment: This is very broad. There are so many ways of doing collision detection, so a [mcve] of your existing collision system and a very clear description of the desired behavior would be necessary to avoid answers that randomly offer physics solutions that won't fit your design or needs, whatever those needs might be.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on multiple factors but the easiest way that I found is to make a standard format for your polygons like this very basic class

```
Polygon{
  type:string
  center:[number, number]
  sides: number //number of points
  rotation:number // Rotation of shape
  points:[...number]  // auto generated from center, sides and rotation


  #generatePoints(){
     this.points = //generatedPoints;
   }


  isTouching(){

   // basic polygon intersection 
   // ex : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838389/javascript-polygon-intersection
   return // the polygon it is intersecting with
  }
 
}
```

Now every polygon has its own isTouching function which makes it more convenient to handle

after that, you just need to move and interact with the shape center and let the auto-generation and the collision function work there magic

Comment: The problem with this is that, in the "level editor", you can make any polygon you want by placing the vertices, and I don't want to have to write a function for each of those blocks you create.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat each shape as a tile, so even though it is not a rectangle, you could do all collisions as if it is a rectangle. That would generally work, but you would not be able to collide on a slope that way, but you could detect that the player is on the slope tile and make it look like it is colliding sloped.  But the normal rout is AABB collision detection; axis aligned bounding boxes.